# Average of different assessment types in different table columns for different subjects for each student in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database

[image]

The above pic is a snapshot of my tables, I need an assistance on how to calculate the average of the sum of the test types for every subject for each student. Don't know if that makes sense. Something like this;

home_work + class_work + test + exam = Total (for all the subjects)

Then for each student:

AVG(Total(Agric) + Total(B.std) + Total(Econs) + Total(F&N)) = Average

And I need the output to be in order of highest score to lowest and look like this;

**first_name**      **last_name**     **Overall_Total**      **Overall_Average**

I really would appreciate any help, cos am still very new to MySQL.

I finally tried the following command:

SELECT student_id, AVG(home_work+class_work+test+exam) AS average FROM scores GROUP BY student_id;

And it gave me the exact output I wanted for the "average" on the pic below.

[[image]

However I still need assistance to add first_name and last_name from the student_info table.

Comment: 1. Add the sample data **and** the expected output based on the sample data as text at least, but an sqlfiddle would be even better. 2. Pls also include what you have tried to avoid the "give me the code" feeling..

Comment: Btw, result of AVG(Total(Agric) + Total(B.std) + Total(Econs) + Total(F&N)) will always be Total(Agric) + Total(B.std) + Total(Econs) + Total(F&N) because you will have 1 record / student. I would say you want AVG(Agric + B.std + Econs + F&N), so basically a simple join, 2 aggregate functions and a group by is needed.

Comment: is the statement you are working not getting the calcs right?

Comment: create a [sqlfiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38899464) and I will upvote this thing

Comment: I would normalise the design

Comment: Please any ideas on how to show another column displaying the position/rank of the students??? From the highest average score to the lowest.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your scores table has a single row per student/subject, you can try:

```
SELECT
    i.first_name,
    i.last_name,
    SUM(s.home_work + s.class_work + s.test + s.exam) AS Overall_Total,
    AVG(s.home_work + s.class_work + s.test + s.exam)/4 AS Overall_Average
FROM scores s
JOIN student_info i ON s.student_id = i.student_id
GROUP BY s.student_id
ORDER BY Overall_Average DESC
```

The `Overall_Average` is divided by 4 since MySQL will calculate the average of the sum of the 4 scores (since I'm adding them together) and won't see them as 4 separate scores.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your assistance. This finally fixed my problem.

SELECT 
student_info.first_name, student_info.last_name,scores.student_id,                       AVG(home_work+class_work+test+exam) AS average 
FROM scores, student_info 
WHERE student_info.student_id=scores.student_id GROUP BY student_id 
ORDER BY average DESC;

Comment: Please any ideas on how to show another column displaying the position/rank of the students??? From the highest average score to the lowest.